# Unable to resolve apiclient.discovery. Intellisense may be missing for this module

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, google-api-python-client, ptvs

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and a Python Tool for Visual Studio. But I can't get the Intellisense to recognize Google API that I installed via `pip install google-api-python-client`.

Here's how my import looks like:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
```

My script runs but I don't get the auto-complete feature.
Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. All I have to do is changing my import statements to:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
```

And now the auto-complete works.